# Changing Safecracker to Channel Form tag results in no form output

Tags: safecracker, channel, safecracker-registration

I recently upgraded from version 2.5.5 to 2.7.0.

To make my forms updated to the current version, I changed forms which uses the `{exp:safecracker}` tag to `{exp:channel:form}`.

When I did, however, the markup inside the tags shows does not show at all.

Is there something I am missing here on why they are not showing at all?

I am using Safecracker Registration btw, but I am not sure if that is the factor.

Comment: Check the channel permissions for the member group you're viewing the form with?

Comment: You are correct. It is indeed caused by channel permissions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a channel permission issue. Thanks to Derek for the answer.